# If a Gett is given on condition the husband does not return what is considered "returning"?

Tags: halacha-theory, divorce, maseches-kesubos, conditional-stipulation, location

Apologies if this is answered simply elsewhere -- I haven't studied the laws of *Gittin*, but this question doesn't seem to be addressed in the connected *mishna* in Gittin 76a.

In Ketuvot, 2b, the text establishes a case -- If a man gives his wife a Gett (divorce) which only becomes valid if he does not "return" within 30 days and then, on day 30, he is stuck on the other side of a river from where they live, the *Gett* becomes valid. People clearly can see him and hear him from across the river  (the text indicates that he, from his side "said to them Look, I have come!" and there is no response that "they can't hear him.")

So what constitutes fully returning? If he crossed the river but stayed on the river bank? Does he have to reach a specific location, or just the city limits? (the earlier formulation was "i have come" which is not the same as "returned" but this distinction isn't explored here as location isn't spoken of)

Answer (score 1):

The Gemora 76b asks regarding the case of  "it should be a Get now if i don't come back here in 12 months time (same would apply with returning to where she lives in 30 days)". How can we even know that he really came back to where his wife lives if the stipulation is between the husband and wife (i.e he could just say he came back and she'll never be divorced (*megureshes misafeik*)as we don't believe her denial)?

> מעכשיו אם לא באתי מכאן ועד י"ב חדש ומת בתוך י"ב חדש ה"ז גט וליחוש שמא פייס אמר רבה בר רב הונא הכי אמר אבא מרי משמיה דרב באומר נאמנת עלי לומר שלא באתי

Rabbah bar Huna answers that he has to make a stipulation that his wife is believed to say that he did not come. i.e when he personally comes back to where she lives and sees her personally  he is divorced. Even if he comes to the house and she doesn't see him it is not considered coming back.

So too in the questioners case the husband completely trusts his wife, so when the husband is waiving on the other side of the river at his wife but has not physically returned to city where he lives, seeing her has no relevance until he returns into his town because thats what she wants and its dependant on her (it seems under normal circumstances returning to their town is good enough to fulfil the stipulation for her if she sees him their). However if she considers only going to her house returning she is also believed as its dependant on her word.